# Adding click event on a specific div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a snowfall effect in JavaScript, I want the create a click event on the 10th snowflake that falls down. I would also like to add a Class that says "clickable". We want to achieve this, so if user clicks the 10th snowflake only, then they will be redirected to a prize (we also want to add a Class so we can style this nicely via CSS).

I must admit, my JavaScript knowledge isn't as strong as my jQuery, so could someone please help? Here is the codepen that I am using:-

https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/GRRzOgO

```
#snowflakeContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.snowflake {
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: fixed;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    user-select: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}

<div id="snowflakeContainer">
    <p class="snowflake">*</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
// The star of every good animation
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

var transforms = ["transform", 
                  "msTransform", 
                  "webkitTransform", 
                  "mozTransform", 
                  "oTransform"];

var transformProperty = getSupportedPropertyName(transforms);

// Array to store our Snowflake objects
var snowflakes = [];

// Global variables to store our browser's window size
var browserWidth;
var browserHeight;

// Specify the number of snowflakes you want visible
var numberOfSnowflakes = 50;

// Flag to reset the position of the snowflakes
var resetPosition = false;

//
// It all starts here...
//
function setup() {
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", generateSnowflakes, false);
  window.addEventListener("resize", setResetFlag, false);
}
setup();

//
// Vendor prefix management
//
function getSupportedPropertyName(properties) {
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        if (typeof document.body.style[properties[i]] != "undefined") {
            return properties[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

//
// Constructor for our Snowflake object
//
function Snowflake(element, radius, speed, xPos, yPos) {

  // set initial snowflake properties
    this.element = element;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;

  // declare variables used for snowflake's motion
    this.counter = 0;
    this.sign = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1;

  // setting an initial opacity and size for our snowflake
    this.element.style.opacity = .1 + Math.random();
    this.element.style.fontSize = 12 + Math.random() * 50 + "px";
}

//
// The function responsible for actually moving our snowflake
//
Snowflake.prototype.update = function () {

  // using some trigonometry to determine our x and y position
    this.counter += this.speed / 5000;
    this.xPos += this.sign * this.speed * Math.cos(this.counter) / 40;
    this.yPos += Math.sin(this.counter) / 40 + this.speed / 30;

  // setting our snowflake's position
    setTranslate3DTransform(this.element, Math.round(this.xPos), Math.round(this.yPos));

    // if snowflake goes below the browser window, move it back to the top
    if (this.yPos > browserHeight) {
      this.yPos = -50;
    }
}

//
// A performant way to set your snowflake's position
//
function setTranslate3DTransform(element, xPosition, yPosition) {
  var val = "translate3d(" + xPosition + "px, " + yPosition + "px" + ", 0)";
    element.style[transformProperty] = val;
}

//
// The function responsible for creating the snowflake
//
function generateSnowflakes() {

  // get our snowflake element from the DOM and store it
    var originalSnowflake = document.querySelector(".snowflake");

    // access our snowflake element's parent container
    var snowflakeContainer = originalSnowflake.parentNode;

    // get our browser's size
  browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    // create each individual snowflake
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSnowflakes; i++) {

      // clone our original snowflake and add it to snowflakeContainer
        var snowflakeCopy = originalSnowflake.cloneNode(true);
        snowflakeContainer.appendChild(snowflakeCopy);

    // set our snowflake's initial position and related properties
        var initialXPos = getPosition(50, browserWidth);
        var initialYPos = getPosition(50, browserHeight);
        var speed = 5+Math.random()*40;
        var radius = 4+Math.random()*10;

        // create our Snowflake object
        var snowflakeObject = new Snowflake(snowflakeCopy, 
                          radius, 
                          speed, 
                          initialXPos, 
                          initialYPos);
        snowflakes.push(snowflakeObject);
    }

    // remove the original snowflake because we no longer need it visible
  snowflakeContainer.removeChild(originalSnowflake);

  // call the moveSnowflakes function every 30 milliseconds
    moveSnowflakes();
}

//
// Responsible for moving each snowflake by calling its update function
//
function moveSnowflakes() {
    for (var i = 0; i < snowflakes.length; i++) {
        var snowflake = snowflakes[i];
        snowflake.update();
    }

  // Reset the position of all the snowflakes to a new value
    if (resetPosition) {
      browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight; 

    for (var i = 0; i < snowflakes.length; i++) {
          var snowflake = snowflakes[i];

          snowflake.xPos = getPosition(50, browserWidth);
          snowflake.yPos = getPosition(50, browserHeight);
      }

      resetPosition = false;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(moveSnowflakes);
}

//
// This function returns a number between (maximum - offset) and (maximum + offset)
//
function getPosition(offset, size) {
  return Math.round(-1*offset + Math.random() * (size+2*offset));
}

//
// Trigger a reset of all the snowflakes' positions
//
function setResetFlag(e) {
  resetPosition = true;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Greatly appreciated

Comment: link code example is broken

Comment: This is working - please try again

Comment: If I correctly understand you just want to add a click listener on a snowfloake and add a class when you clik on it ?

Comment: No, the class needs to be added to the 10th snowflake when page loads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When generating the snowflakes, try to catch the 10th one and apply what you want

````js
...

function generateSnowflakes() {
...
    // create each individual snowflake
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSnowflakes; i++) {

      // clone our original snowflake and add it to snowflakeContainer
        var snowflakeCopy = originalSnowflake.cloneNode(true);
        snowflakeContainer.appendChild(snowflakeCopy);

        // <------------------------------------------>
        // catch the tenth snowflake and add your changes here
        if (i === 9) {
          snowflakeCopy.classList.add("clickable");
          snowflakeCopy.addEventListener("click",function (e) {
            //the stuff you want to do
            //when the 10th snowflake is clicked
            // for example :
            window.location.replace("URL/OF/PRIZE");
          })
        }
....
}
...


```
````